# Service fabric container not allowing http/s calls to extrnal API's

Tags: c#, api, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless, .net-core-2.2

I'm busy creating some microservices using the Service Fabric mesh, and these services will be making some calls to external API's.

Im using .net core 2.2.

My interservice communication works fine, all the services can talk to one another,  but when i try and make a call to an external API, one thats not hosted on my machine, the connection cannot be made and the call fails.

I have check in Fiddler 4 and i don't see any traffic to the urls i'm trying to call, this happens for both HTTP and HTTPS calls, GET and POST.

**EDIT**

I'm behind a proxy, and it feels like this could be the reason.

**Edit 2**

I have determined that this is due to our proxy, when connected to a personal connection, the calls work properly.
Although, when i run the same code and tests froma normal cmd app and not from within a conatainer the call works.

How do i get around this?

Comment: Were you able to get this resolved?

Comment: No, when running on my local cluster it doesn't work.

Once i deployed it to azure it worked fine.

Comment: Well that's good at least. Were you still looking to debug locally or the end goal of getting in Azure and now that it is working is good enough?

Comment: I still have quite a few sprints ahead of me, so i would need to be able to debug locally again eventually, because deploying to my test env in azure is not the best option

Comment: Got it. If you like, I can get you in touch with support to help debug further. You can email me at AzCommunity@microsoft.com and provide me with your SubscriptionID and link to this thread. I can enable your subscription for a free support request.